# Making a fading header in table view, like in notes app

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I want to make a little player tab above my table view,so it should always hidden,only with a little 1px string visible,like in notes app,and when you scroll to the top,it should appear,but stay on top,not going down,like all the cells in table view.
It cant't be header,because its always visible, and it can't be a cell,cause it must be on top.
So i want to do everything just like in notes app,how can i do that?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is my idea.

1. Add `UITableView` and `UIImageView` as subviews of the underlying `UIView`. `UIImageView` instance is the representation of the 'string/stripe' (whatever you call it)
2. Create two cell prototypes. One for normal cell, and one for the header cell.
3. For the first cell (`indexPath.row == 0`), always use the header cell prototype. For other cells, use normal cell prototype.
4. In `viewWillAppear`, always scroll to the second row using `[UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]`

Below is my sample code snippet. (It worked as I expected at least)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

    self.overlayView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stripe.png"]]; // This is an image with stripe with transparent background
    self.overlayView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 10);
    [self.view addSubview:self.overlayView];
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSIndexPath * indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // It is important that the table has enough rows to scroll. Otherwise, [UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath...] will not take effect.
    return 20;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell * cell;
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        // This is an example of header cell
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"topCell"];
        if(!cell)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"topCell"];
            [cell.textLabel setText:@"This is the play tab"];            
        }        
    }
    else
    {
        // This is an example of normal cell
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"normalCell"];
        if(!cell)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:@"normalCell"];
        }        
        [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Data at : %d", indexPath.row - 1]];
        [cell.detailTextLabel setText:@"A normal cell."];
    }    
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Don't think it should work the way i want.Will it dissappear,lrpeaving just one little stringa.and why do you think it wouldn't scroll down?

Comment: If you specify `NO` to the last parameter of `[UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]`, then it won't have "scroll" animation when appearing. It will show the table just from the second row as if the second row is the top row. But I missed the string-on-the-top part. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: But when the user will do that pull down the table view,this cell will scroll down too,right? But i don't want that to happen.i want it to stay up there,like in notes.like if it was a part of navigation bar

Comment: Ah, I see. I looked the Notes application and realized my mistake. Okay, I think you can just add the stripe as an overlay. So, 1. the player tab can be the top cell as I proposed originally. 2. the stripe can be simply an overlay UIView with transparent background. One thing to note is that both your tableView and overlay-view need to be subviews of underlying UIView. If you make your overlay-view as a subview of your tableView, then the overlay-view will scroll along with the table. I will edit my answer when I have time...

Comment: thank you,that starts making sense to me,how to manage that out!

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is only one way to achieve this effect. You should use scrollViewDidScroll:  method. You lay a subview on your table and calculate appropriate coordinates for it every time the table scrolls. It could be a bit tedious to describe all possible conditions, but there is nothing tricky.